# New android:gradle commandline app doesn't show first screen, just buzzes black

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

I had a working project built from command-line Ant which I converted to Gradle 2.12 from scratch.
I installed it with Gradle installDebugAndroidTest (via USB) but when I run it (on a Samsung with Android 4.0.4) it just shows a black screen, with the correct header line, and buzzes. 
Normally the header line goes away after about 15sec.
If I click the black screen and there's an icon hidden underneath, it will run it!
It doesn't show a log message at the start of the main Activity's onCreate although logcat is working for the Ant version.

BREAKING NEWS:

```
With this in AndroidManifest.xml:    
    <activity           
        android:name=".CloxActivity"       

I looked at the Stack Trace and got:      
E/AndroidRuntime( 2147): FATAL EXCEPTION: main    
E/AndroidRuntime( 2147): java.lang.RuntimeException:   
Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo   
{com.Chatterton.Peter.Clox.test/com.Chatterton.Peter.Clox.CloxActivity}   
:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.Chatterton.Peter.Clox.CloxActivity
```

There's that 'test' again

All the code is here!
Hope you can help.

## Gradle output:

```
...    
:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebugAndroidTest UP-TO-DATE
:validateDebugSigning
:packageDebugAndroidTest
:assembleDebugAndroidTest
:installDebugAndroidTest
Installing APK 'Clox-debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk' on 'GT-S7560M - 4.0.4'   for Clox:debugAndroidTest
Installed on 1 device.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

FWIW Gradle installDebugAndroid gives the same output
When it refers to 'Test', could that be the 'Test' version -- the one I don't want?

My file is: D:\Android\Clox\build\outputs\apk\Clox-debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk

I'm tried to use the Gradle file locations.
eg 
    D:\Android\Clox\build\generated\source\r\release\com\Chatterton\Peter\Clox\R.java
    D:\Android\Clox\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
    D:\Android\Clox\src\main\CloxActivity.java
    D:\Android\Clox\src\main\res\layout\main.xml
    D:\Android\Clox\src\main\res\values\strings.xml

The basic upload functionality is there because I damaged AndroidManifest.xml by removing the MAIN intent-filter and the install worked, but there was nothing to see, as you would expect.

I've just upgraded to Gradle 1.13

## build.gradle

```
buildscript{
    System.properties['com.android.build.gradle.overrideVersionCheck'] = 'true'
    repositories{
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies{
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android{
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    buildTypes{
        debug{
            debuggable true
        }
    }
}
```

## AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
delete for debugging the black, buzzing load problem
see d:\android\clox\tempBackup
    <activity
              android:name="SettingsActivity"
              android:label="@string/action_settings">
    </activity>
```

also delete this:
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    -->

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.Chatterton.Peter.Clox"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0"
          android:screenOrientation="landscape" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>

    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        >

        <activity
                  android:name="com.Chatterton.Peter.Clox.CloxActivity"    
                  android:label="@string/app_name">  
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest >
```

## main.xml

```
I've simplified main.xml and here's all of it:
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/left_text"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="15:00"
            android:textSize="55sp"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:background="@color/lgt_green"
            android:paddingEnd="50dp"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

## CloxActivity.java

```
package com.Chatterton.Peter.Clox;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class CloxActivity extends Activity
    {
    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
        {
        //int x = 1/0;
        Log.d( "clox", "CCA, onCreate-1" );
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView(R.layout.main);      // * (res\layout\main.xml) old note
// * D:\Android\Clox\build\generated\source\r\release\com\Chatterton\Peter\Clox\R.java    


        Log.d( "clox", "CCA, onCreate-2" );
        }     
    }
```

FYI: I removed the closing '}' from this class and it still compiled!

Answer (score 0):

start `android:name` with point or type full package name:
      `<activity
                  android:name=".CloxActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>`

Comment: Thanks Maxim, but I tried both    
            android:name="com.Chatterton.Peter.Clox"
and                
            android:name=".CloxActivity"
and it still crashes black and buzzy.